# XAML MVVM DatePicker - How do I get the data?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, datepicker

I've got a View with a DatePicker bound to a DateTime property in my ViewModel.  However, the date value always appears as null, even when I select a different value than the default.  Anyone have success with the DatePicker?  If so, what am I getting wrong?

Relevant Code:

View:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="startDateUpdatePick" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="1.5" 
   Text="{Binding SelectedProjectData.ProjectStartDate, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, TargetNullValue=''}"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
public PSViewModel()
    {
        SelectedProjectData = new Project();
    }
```

Model:

```
public class Project : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private DateTime _projectStartDate;

    public DateTime ProjectStartDate
    {
        get { return _projectStartDate; }
        set
        {
            _projectStartDate = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string caller = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }
}
```

Edit: the XAML is bound to a non-nullable DateTime, but I have other datepickers in the same setup that are bound to nullable DateTime and they don't work either.

Comment: What's the DataContext of the DatePicker?  And your ViewModel won't even compile, so who knows what's actually going on in there.  Project looks correct.

Comment: Also, grab you a copy of Snoop.  You can investigate binding errors easily at runtime.

Comment: is SelectedProjectData  a public property? Is your view's DataContext set to an instance of PSViewModel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property is `SelectedDate`, not `Text`.

When I was a starveling lad, growing up homeless and feral in the lawless, filthy, labyrinthine back alleys of Palo Alto, I once met an ancient, dying one-eyed beggar. He held my thin little arm in an iron, clawlike grip, drew me close, and imparted to me the root of all earthly wisdom with his final, rasping breath:

[*Read... the... documentation...*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)

He looked exactly like Marty Feldman.

Comment: Fair point.  Thank you, Ed.  Although, I would hope you could see my point of confusion, even had I been a dilligent student of the documentation... "Text: Gets the text that is displayed by the DatePicker, or sets the selected date."  and... "SelectedDate: Gets or sets the currently selected date."  They're so close that I would hope I would avoid the lash.  :)  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DocHoss Yeah, it's definitely not the most clear thing. My girlfriend says "the documentation sucks"

Comment: Sounds like a smart lady.  Thanks again, Ed.

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding SelectedDate, 
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        DisplayDateStart="{Binding StartDate}" DisplayDateEnd="{Binding EndDate}"/>
    <Label Content="{Binding SelectedDate}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

ViewModel

```
   public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _selectedDate;
        public string SelectedDate
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedDate;
            }
            set
            {
                _selectedDate = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            StartDate = new DateTime(2020, 1, 1);
            EndDate = new DateTime(2020, 3, 31);
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```